# Best practice of transpose part of the data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to find a way to transpose only 1 column in my R data frame.

This is the original data frame:

```
Fruits  Name  Count
Apple   Tom   2
Apple   Bob   2
Banana  Tom   1
```

This is what I want my data frame to be:

```
Name  Apple Banana
Tom   2     1
Bob   2     0
```

Please advice and thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to [reshape from long to wide](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/)? If so, [here is another SO post of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format).

Comment: Try this `library(tidyverse); df %>%   spread(Fruits, Count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @bbiasi data:

```
tidyr::spread(df2, Fruits, Count, fill = 0)

#  Name Apple Banana
#1  Bob     2      0
#2  Tom     2      1
```

*upd: haven't seen @Jilber Urbina comment, before I posted this*

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(Fruits = c("Apple", "Apple", "Banana"),
                 Name = c("Tom", "Bob", "Tom"),
                 Count = c(2,2,1))
df
```

```
> df
  Fruits Name Count
1  Apple  Tom     2
2  Apple  Bob     2
3 Banana  Tom     1
```

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key = Fruits, value = Count) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(Name))
df2
```

```
> df2
  Name Apple Banana
1  Tom     2      1
2  Bob     2      0
```